# Graphql value in Twitter API

Tags: twitter, graphql

What is the `6SBWVfRVIH0h71ssRzNVUg` value in `https://twitter.com/i/api/graphql/6SBWVfRVIH0h71ssRzNVUg/Followers?variables={"userId":"1234567","count":20,"withHighlightedLabel":false,"withTweetQuoteCount":false,"includePromotedContent":false,"withTweetResult":false,"withUserResult":false}` ?

Twitter now uses Graphql to retrieve the followers list, in both the Web version and the mobile API. There are no previous requests to get the `6SBWVfRVIH0h71ssRzNVUg` value, and it's not constant. It changes with every request. The problem is I can't use the same value for another account.

Comment: looks like 'persisted query' (only query id [known for both BE/FE] + variables passed) but with dynamic id - combined with some nonce [/token/session/whatever]

Comment: Yes. i managed to found out how to get for the Web version (Form Js script). But I'm still looking for the Mobile app version @xadm

Comment: This is not a public API. You should not be calling this API. Your App and IP address may (and will) be blocked. This is against the developer policy and Twitter Terms of Service.

Comment: The is for academic purples only @AndyPiper

Comment: There is no public GraphQL API for Twitter and you should not be calling this endpoint. The value of the key you’re trying to use is not documented for external use.

Comment: @AndyPiper I have been using this API for a very long time for scrapping and it has been working fine so far. No ban. Anyway I am using proxy servers so it does not matter if they ban IP. Be careful and cheers mate.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: As far as I can see its value depends only on next path part and it looks like an md5 of it plus some salt.